# Solving a non-linear equation in Mathematica with many variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation, nonlinear-functions

I have a beautiful equation, where I am trying to compute for R2. I am using Mathematica.  So far every single time that I have tried to use Solve[] or Reduce [] the computation takes forever. I hope You can help me what to do with this beauty in order to get a solution. Thank you! Below is my equation.

```
eq1 = (R2 + ((((p2x - R2*(vac2y + voby)) - (k1x + 
              vox ((vobx ((p2y + R2*(vac2x + vobx)) - k1y) + 
                   voby (k1x - (p2x - R2*(vac2y + voby))))/(-voby*
                    vox + vobx*voy))))^2 + ((p2y + 
              R2*(vac2x + vobx)) - ((p2y + R2*(vac2x + vobx)) - 
              voby ((vox (k1y - (p2y + R2*(vac2x + vobx))) + 
                   voy ((p2x - R2*(vac2y + voby)) - k1x))/(-voby*vox +
                    vobx*voy))))^2)^0.5))/
   v2 == (R1 + (((k1x - (k1x + 
              vox ((vobx ((p2y + R2*(vac2x + vobx)) - k1y) + 
                   voby (k1x - (p2x - R2*(vac2y + voby))))/(-voby*
                    vox + vobx*voy))))^2 + (k1y - ((p2y + 
                R2*(vac2x + vobx)) - 
              voby ((vox (k1y - (p2y + R2*(vac2x + vobx))) + 
                   voy ((p2x - R2*(vac2y + voby)) - k1x))/(-voby*vox +
                    vobx*voy))))^2)^0.5))/v1
```

Comment: Probably better asked at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.  This smacks of a combination of maths and programming and the people over there are probably more likely to be able to help than us script-kiddies.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a shot :)

Comment: You should also look at your equation a bit, you might be able to reduce it by hand. At first glance, it seems to me that `p2x` only appears as `p2x-R2*(vac2y+voby)` and `p2y` as `p2y+R2*(vac2x+vobx)`, and similar reused blocks might be used to simplify the equation (on paper).

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would note is that it is better to use ^(1/2) or Sqrt[] than ^0.5: Mathematica is very careful to distinguish between real numbers (with decimal points) and integers or rationals.

Even if you make that change, though, I fear the probability of getting a nice analytical solution is small. If you think about the ways you would rearrange the equation to get rid of the square roots, you would end up having to square twice so you will end up with a quartic equation. In principle that is analytically soluble, but only in special cases is the solution compact enough to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is of this form:

```
 a + Sqrt[b + c R2 + d R2^2] == e R2 + Sqrt[f + g R2 + h R2^2]
```

`Solve` readily returns four solutions.
Now just work out those parameters (`a,b,c..`) in terms of your original parameters (`vox,voy,..`,etc)  and substitute into the `Solve` result.  (I suspect the result is too unwieldy to be of practical use though.)